# Remove Square Brackets in Text and its contents

Tags: c#, .net, regex

I have a string which contains normal English words as well as certain information displayed inside square brackets (`[` and `]`).

I need to remove all the square brackets and its contents from the string.

For example, the string below:

> String: "The dog[0] had a bone [1][2]"

needs to be reformed to:

> String: "The dog had a bone"

Comment: Why would you want to use regex for such a simple task? The way I'd do it? Iterate over the string's characters keeping track of open and closed brackets (a simple counter would do; +1 for every [ and -1 for every ]). If counter is not zero then ignore the current character, else append it to the new string.

Comment: @InBetween what if the counter goes negative "a[b]c]d]e]f[g]"

Comment: @icemanind I fail to see where my algorithm would fail with your example. As long as counter > 0 it will ignore characters. The only flaw is malformed input strings (unmatched brackets). In this case I'd bail out with an argument exception as OP didn't specify if this is even possible

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
\[[^]]*\]
```

Try this.Replace by `empty string`.See demo.

http://regex101.com/r/xT7yD8/2

Comment: I don't think this would work for unmatched square brackets or nested square brackets, like "abc[d[e]f]" would become "abcf]".

Comment: @juharr OP has not suggested the same