# In SpectreConsole, how to strip the tags to get a plain text string?

Tags: c#, .net, console-application, spectre.console

I'm using `Spectre.Console` and have plenty of `AnsiConsole.MarkupLine` commands like this:

```cs
AnsiConsole.MarkupLine($"[lime]File size:[/] [bold]\t{file.Length,-10}[/]");
```

I'd like to output the same text in plaintext with no color in a text file, like

```cs
var msg = $"[lime]File size:[/] [bold]\t{file.Length,-10}[/]"
AnsiConsole.MarkupLine(msg);
var msgclean = AnsiConsole.StripTag(msg);
LogToFile(msgclean);
```

Is there a way to strip the tags? Or redirect the console output some way to a file?

Answer (score 1):

I dug through their API and found this extension method that should do the trick : `RemoveMarkup()` https://spectreconsole.net/api/spectre.console/stringextensions/29bfb33e

Answer (score 0):

See if the following language extension will work for you. Regex pattern taken from [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26285675/5509738). Try via [dotnetfiddle](https://dotnetfiddle.net/ijNYRq).

```
public static class StringExtensions
{
    private static readonly Regex Whitespace = new(@"\s+");

    public static string Flatten(this string value)
        => value is null or "" ?
            value :
            Whitespace.Replace(value.Trim(), " ");

    public static string StripCodes(this string sender)
        => Regex.Replace(sender, @"\[[^]]*\]", "")
            .Flatten();
}
```